# FirebaseDatabaseUI has swift compiler error Xcode 8 Swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, xcode8, firebaseui

I got latest FirebaseDatabaseUI by cocoapods, but the problem is whenever I import it the following error appears.[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLe3t.png)

Comment: Where are you trying to import it? If you are using a bridging header no import statements should be necessary.

Comment: No, I just used cocoa pods installation process, as explained the FirebaseUI GitHub page

Comment: I used

Import FirebaseDatabaseUI, is there another way to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write this at the top of your podfile:

`use_frameworks!`

and reinstall pods.